# awk + print lines only if second field match hours:min:sec

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, awk, perl

log file is like this

```
34.3.23.58  07:20:01  AM                          all     0.02        0.00      0.02     0.00     0.00    99.97
34.3.23.58  07:30:01  AM                          all     0.02        0.00      0.02     0.00     0.00    99.97
34.3.23.58  07:40:01  AM                          all     0.02        0.00      0.02     0.00     0.00    99.97
34.3.23.58  Average:  all                         0.02    0.00        0.02      0.00     0.00     99.96
34.3.23.60  Linux     3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64  (dns)  09/25/2019  _x86_64_  (4       CPU)
```

we want to capture only the lines when second field is hour:min:sec

as the following expected results

```
cat info.txt 

34.3.23.58  07:20:01  AM                          all     0.02        0.00      0.02     0.00     0.00    99.97
34.3.23.58  07:30:01  AM                          all     0.02        0.00      0.02     0.00     0.00    99.97
34.3.23.58  07:40:01  AM                          all     0.02        0.00      0.02     0.00     0.00    99.97
```

we try

```
cat info.txt | awk '$2 =~ [0-9][0-9]/:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]'
```

but run with errors

```
awk: cmd. line:1: $2 =~ [0-9][0-9]/:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]
awk: cmd. line:1:     ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: $2 =~ [0-9][0-9]/:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: $2 =~ [0-9][0-9]/:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]
awk: cmd. line:1:                ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: $2 =~ [0-9][0-9]/:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]
awk: cmd. line:1:                  ^ unterminated regexp
```

Comment: What errors? More detail will let people help you quicker

Comment: see please my update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right syntax is

```
<info.txt awk '$2 ~ /^[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]$/'
```

Changes:

- No useless use of `cat`.
- The operator is `~`.
- The pattern needs to be embraced by slashes (`/regex/`).
- `^` and `$` match the beginning and the end of the matched string (here `$2`) respectively.